# Median of same columns in different data frames

Tags: r

I have three data frames (`a,b,c`).

```
a
aa ab  ac
1  2   5
2  3   6
3  4   7
b
aa  ab  ac
2   5    8
4   6    9
c
aa  ab  ac
5   4    6
7   1    8
```

I need to calculate median of same columns of different data frames. I have heard of `abind` but when i tried it combined all 3 data frames without any median calculation. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Try `library(data.table); rbindlist(list(a,b,c), idcol=TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) median(as.numeric(x))) , by = .id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `rbind` all the datasets, create a grouping id, and get the `median` of individual columns

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(a, b, c, .id="group") %>% 
              group_by(group) %>% 
              summarise_each(funs(median))
```

If we don't need to group it by 'id'

```
bind_rows(a, b, c)  %>% 
             summarise_each(funs(median))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(a,b,c), idcol=TRUE)[, 
         lapply(.SD, function(x) median(as.numeric(x))) , by = .id]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the median of the columns of your dataframes separately you have to do

- for dataframe a:
- `median(a$aa)`
- `median(a$ab)`
- `median(a$ac)`
  and so on for the rest of the dataframes

IF you want to get the median for all three data frames consider the following:

```
big_df = cbind(a,b,c)
median(big_df$aa)
median(big_df$ab)
median(big_df$ac)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the median you can do

```
apply(df[, c("cols on which median should be calculated")], 2, median, na.rm=T)
```

For the big table see the approches in the other answers.